# Add a 'I have found a security-related issue' line to the reasons combobox in the 'Contact us' form

Tags: feature-request, security, contact

Related:

- [Should I report a serious security issue on meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22067/should-i-report-a-serious-security-issue-on-meta)
- [How do I report a possible security vulnerability?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/security-reports)

Rationale: discoverability without having to jump through several hoops.

Side note: [Security hole: password change dialog doesn't ask for a user's current password](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232256/can-we-fix-the-security-hole-in-the-password-change-dialog-and-ask-for-a-users) has been going on for a year with the team evidently unwilling to comment.

Comment: FWIW, the security page with instructions for submitting reports shows up in the top few results when I Google things like "stack exchange report security issue", so I don't think the process is *too* bad.