# I found a bug in Stack Exchange, where should I report?

Tags: support, bug-reports

I have found some bug in the current implementation of Stack Overflow. Since there is no specific thing like "bug bounty" on Stack Exchange, I am framing it as a question on Meta.

Can I contact any of Stack Exchange members here and can get some kind of reward (if bug accepted)?

Comment: What kind of bug are you talking about? Stack Exchange do not have a bug bounty award system.

Comment: Your reward is the warm and fuzzy feeling inside that you get for making the community better for everyone.

Comment: @Oded Able to find a way to perform some action on stackoverflow, even without having enough points

Comment: Then post it on any meta site - either this one or the Stack Overflow one.

Comment: So is there any provision of awarding reputation points or something else.?

Comment: No. There are no such provisions. Reputation is earned by making positive actions on the site.

Comment: If you are talking about the comment that you have on someone else post - that was an autoconverted answer, which was too short to be a proper answer so got converted to a comment. This is by design.

Comment: @Oded, re: `Reputation is earned by making positive actions on the site.` that statement would seem to imply that bug reporting is *not* a positive action.

Comment: @agc how exactly? As you can see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a152859%20%5bbug%5d%20is%3aq) I made thousands of reputation points by posting bug reports here. (Make sure to click "active" tab after you take a look, so you won't stick with sorting by votes.)

Comment: Also very related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277737/establishing-a-security-bug-bounty-programme-for-stack-exchange.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, kudos on the reports, but please do not mistake my own opinion with an ironical implication of *Oded*'s hasty generalization.

Comment: @agc - I don't see how that follows. Make positive action -> gain reputation.  How that implies report bug -> bad action, I don't know.

Comment: @Oded said: *"No. There are no such provisions [of bounties for bug reporting]. Reputation is earned by making positive actions on the site."* which tends to imply...(see previous message).  Apparently, you must have meant something like: `"Reputation is earned by making positive actions on the site, but no, there are no such provisions [of bounties for bug reporting]."`

Comment: @Haney ...says a prison guard in North Korea. Well guess what - studies show people work hardest when they receive personal benefit and contribute back to the community

Answer (score 5):

Any meta site is ok for most bugs. Just tag your question with [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and the appropriated component (comments if the bug is related to comments for example), and describe the means to reproduce the problem, what you expected and what happened instead.

For security bugs, those that puts in jeopardy the users or the site correct functionality, may be reported using the "contact us" link included in the footer of all sites.