# Is my Stack Overflow account protected vs identify theft?

Tags: discussion

Under ***"SITE SETTINGS > MY LOGINS"*** one may remove all related email addresses and add other emails.

Now I wonder, if someone hacks my SO account, removes my logins and creates a new login with a new mail - is there any chance that I get back my old account or is it simply lost?

Comment: In a case such as this, I'm pretty sure you could just contact SE staff directly. They have all the logs and can see login IPs et all and when credentials change.

Comment: You'd need to use the contact link at the bottom of the page to contact SE

Comment: Already answered by the question [Logins can be added/removed without reauthenticating, allowing temporary XSS to be escalated to permanent account hijacking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276933/logins-can-be-added-removed-without-reauthenticating-allowing-temporary-xss-to). At least it shows that your worries are correct and that Stack Exchange needs to do something against it.